# How to add custom file from var/log to newrelic

Tags: magento2, log, newrelic

I need to see some logs that I saved in /var/debug.log on NewRelic logs.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

using below code you can write your data in var/log/ directory.

```
$data = "Hello World !";
$filename = "logFileName.log";
$permission= "a+";
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$directory = $om->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$rootPath  =  $directory->getRoot();
$file = fopen($rootPath."/var/log/".$filename,$permission);
fwrite($file,json_encode($data)."\n");
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

the custom log file created using the below code

Magento 2.4.2 before version use this

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message'); 
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```

for Magento 2.4.2 or after version use this

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new  \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```